# Merging unregistered accounts for better traceability?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

There are 74 accounts belonging to the [emailhash b60d6b835a36491ae1fddecd1265894d](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/137286) (with a notable overall [score](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/137323/score-by-b60d6b835a36491ae1fddecd1265894d)). Does this really indicate that they belong to the same person resp. email address?

Would it make sense to merge these accounts for better traceability?

**EDIT**
@mrf: [Here's](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/135571/168187) the full list...

Comment: I assume you didn't find these by searching for random hashes?

Comment: @mrf unfortunately I removed my query to prove it, but 'b60d6b835a36491ae1fddecd1265894d' was just one example...

Answer (score 16):

From a sample of several of these accounts, they do all appear to be the same user, who has not registered an account and seems to clear their cookies between each visit to the site.

It would make sense to merge them. However, moderators can no longer merge users; it must be done either by the user themselves or the StackExchange team. Since there does not appear to be any malicious or rule-breaking activity coming from these users, I see no reason to bother the team with merging them.

Comment: Why can't moderators no longer merge users? Is there a reason?

Comment: @draks... Merging is a rather dangerous operation, and if you're wrong then you are granting access to the account to a completely unrelated person, which is a rather big privacy issue.

Comment: Is it not possible that this (or any similar) user has a reason for not wanting their unregistered accounts merged? Unless that reason is malicious I feel we should respect such a users intentions.

Comment: Maybe it's some dummy email address like "mail@mail.com"